# How to view or retrieve data from hyperledger fabric

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I have modified fabcar example to store my own data which have keys like this `5e57b8dbb9b30e3575f45d75,5e57b8dbb9b30e3575f45d76`.

I used `getStateByRange` to get data, but it retrieves only certain data between the range. Is there any way to retrieve all the data or based on the timestamp of data

Also how can to view the GUI of couchDB which is running in the fabcar example.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can view a CouchDB GUI on `http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils` URL, If you run your fabric locally if you have any server then check `docker ps` command output and get your couchDB **port number**.

And in fabric you want query for all data then use `getQueryResult` method it will give you all data.

for example:

```
let queryString = {
      "selector": {}
 }

let resultsIterator = await ctx.stub.getQueryResult(JSON.stringify(queryString));
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: One comment. If you want **all** data (and your number of records exceeds `totalQueryLimit`), you must use `getQueryResultWithPagination` to get the data paginated. Otherwise, `getQueryResult` is not able to return more than `totalQueryLimit` results (100000 by default, as defined in `core.yaml` or redefined via environment variable).

Comment: Even when your records are less than `totalQueryLimit`, you probably don't want to return thousands of records in a single response, so let's paginate.

Comment: cab9e4f94488        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb                                                                               "tini -- /docker-ent…"   6 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7984->5984/tcp   couchdb2
1e7364876fe6        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb  => This is the response receiving from docker ps. But i can't able to view the couchdb.

Comment: Nope it is not working. Getting site can't be reached error.